# Why is my dictionary not appending correctly? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have blocks of CNC code I'm trying to parse information out of. The blocks are fairly repetative so I thought loading them to a dictionary would make sense and parsing by keywords in the block. As a sample here's what one looks like:

```
%
O4001(AARD0509280 REV-C 1-11-13) 
(SAVE 4001-S206) 
(BODY.187 EDUCTOR-SPEC)
(UPDATED 02-09-16) 

M91
M94002 

N1(SET UP)G0G18G40G97G99T0 
M60
M11
G4U.2
G300X[[#2708+#2008]-.06]Z1.T0800 
G150Z.438
M10
G4U.2
G0Z-.05
G28U0
M1 

N2(FACE) 
T2121
M3S3000P1
M8 
G99G0X.25Z0
G1X-.02F.001 
Z-.02F.01
G0Z-.05T0
G28U0
M1
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is every time an `Nx` or `Nxx` hits I'd like to append to a new key in the dictionary. Every block always starts with an `Nxx` and ends with an `M1`.

What I've tried is variations of this:

```
# iterate thru files
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root + '\\'):
    for file in files:
        src = os.path.join(path, file)
        o = open(src, 'r') # , encoding='Latin-1'
        idx_name = 'Heading'
        for line in o.readlines():
            if line[0] == 'N':
                N = line.split('(')
                N = N[0]
                idx_name = N
            program_dict[idx_name] = line
        break
    break
print(program_dict)
```

It looks to me like every line should append to the latest `idx_name` (key) of the dictionary, only renaming is a new `Nxx` pops up. This is what is outputting though:

```
{
    "Heading": " \n",
    "N1": " \n",
    "N2": " \n",
    "N3": " \n",
    "N4": " \n",
    "N5": " \n",
    "N6": " \n",
    "N7": " \n",
    "N8 ": " \n",
    "N9": " \n",
    "N10 ": " \n",
    "N11": " \n",
    "N12": " \n",
    "N13": " \n",
    "N14 ": " \n",
    "N15 ": " \n",
    "N16": " \n",
    "N17": " \n",
    "N18": " \n",
    "N19": "%"
}
```

Obviously I'm breaking for troubleshooting so there's shouldn't be this many, but this is the format I'm expecting the dictionary to be in:

```
heading: %, O4001(AARD0509280 REV-C 1-11-13), (SAVE 4001-S206), (BODY.187 EDUCTOR-SPEC), (UPDATED 02-09-16), M91, M94002
N1: N1(SET UP)G0G18G40G97G99T0, G4U.2, G300X[[#2708+#2008]-.06]Z1.T0800, G150Z.438, M10, G4U.2,G0Z-.05, G28U0, M1 
N2: N2(FACE), T2121, M3S3000P1, M8, G99G0X.25Z0, G1X-.02F.001, Z-.02F.01, G0Z-.05T0, G28U0, M1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is, that `program_dict[idx_name] = line` always replaces the value with the key of `ìdx_name` with `line`, so that that entry will always only contain the last line before the next `Nxx`. To append `line`, use `+=`. However, if the entry doesn't exist yet, this will raise an exception, which is why you will have to check for this:

```
if idx_name in program_dict:
    program_dict[idx_name] += line
else:
    program_dict[idx_name] = line
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a more elegant solution after briefly looking at the documentation of the dictionary type; alternatively, you could also create the entry before you start looping by just inserting

```
program_dict[idx_name] = str()
```

after which you can safely append to it.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, `program_dict[idx_name] = N` is not in the code I provided

Comment: @55thSwiss Sorry, my bad. I meant line instead of N. The edited answer should now actually help you.

Comment: I thought that's what you meant and had tried it already, unfortunately it raises an exception which doesn't make sense to me. There's nothing wrong with `Heading`


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e13acaf908ee> in <module>
     19             #    lista.append(line)
     20             #program_dict.update({idx_name : lista})
---> 21             program_dict[idx_name] += line
     22         break
     23     break

KeyError: 'Heading'

Comment: Sorry for the new lines of commented code in there, I was trying to create a list of lines in the mean time and then append that to the dictionary

Comment: The problem probably stems from the entry not existing before appending to it with +=; I have updated my answer to make up for that. Alternatively, you should also take a look at Mahmoud's solution.

Comment: There are several incredibly common approaches to giving a `dict`-like object default initial values, including `get` and `defaultdict`. Familiarize yourself with Pythons standard idioms.